# I need help with comma with conjunction

Tags: commas

Should there be a comma before "and" in the sentence below? The reason why I ask is because I think that the sentence below has committed a comma splice, but I am not completely sure. Can someone please explain to me why there is a comma in front of "and".

> Birmingham lighted a runaway fuse, and as fast as the headlines could record them, demonstrations exploded all over the country...

Comment: That’s perfectly normal. You have two independent clauses separated by a coördinating conjunction and a comma.

Comment: Is "and as fast as the headlines could record them, demonstrations exploded all over the country" in this case treated as an independent clause?

Comment: Yes, it is an independent clause. The sentence, in my opinion, is not a good one. It lacks clarity. A better rendering could be, "Birmingham lit a runaway fuse, and demonstrations exploded all over the country as fast as the headlines could record them." (At 2AM, that sentence is the best I can come up with!)

Comment: @rhetorician the original sentence has "lighted."  That isn't correct, is it?  I think it should be "lit" as you wrote it.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Lighted or lit: which is correct? Both! See this web site:  http://grammarist.com/usage/lighted-lit/.  See also this ngram entry:  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lighted%2Clit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clighted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clit%3B%2Cc0.  Don

Answer (score 0):

Because both sentences can stand independently, a comma is required before the conjunction.

Source: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/commas.htm

Comment: The 'rule' is not hard and fast, as the balanced linked article at the duplicate says.